# How do I programmatically add new functions to current scope in Python?

Tags: python, function, dynamic, python-3.x, scope

In Python [it is easy to create new functions programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582521/python-creating-dynamic-functions). How would I assign this to programmatically determined names in the current scope?

This is what I'd like to do (in non-working code):

```
obj_types = ('cat', 'dog', 'donkey', 'camel')
for obj_type in obj_types:
    'create_'+obj_type = lambda id: id
```

In the above example, the assignment of `lambda` into a to-be-determined function name obviously does not work. In the real code, the function itself would be created by a function factory.

The background is lazyness and do-not-repeat-yourself: I've got a dozen and more object types for which I'd assign a generated function. So the code currently looks like:

```
create_cat   = make_creator('cat')
# ...
create_camel = make_creator('camel')
```

The functions `create_cat` etc are used hardcoded in a parser.

If I would create classes as a new type programmatically, `types.new_class()` as seen in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) seems to be the solution.
Is it my best bet to (mis)use this approach?

Comment: You can create a variable with `locals()[name] = value`

Comment: related: [generating variable names on fly in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4010840/4279)

Comment: @Vaughn: Oh! That is simple, indeed. Why not convert it into an answer?

Comment: @VaughnCato: you shouldn't use `locals()` in that way.

Comment: related: [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via to a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5036700/4279)

Comment: @Vaughn: To provide the reasoning behind J.F.'s rejection of using `locals()` that way, here's what the [docs think about that](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals): "Note: 
The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter"

Comment: if you want to create (class/instance) methods programmatically; you could use class decorators, metaclasses, mixins. Here's [an example that shows how to create properties dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922028/4279).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you are trying to do (but not create functions with dynamic names) is to store the lamda's in a `dict` using the name as the key.  Instead of calling `create_cat()` you would call `create['cat']()`.  That would dovetail nicely with not hardcoding names in the parser logic as well.

Comment: This answer and the comment by J.F. Sebastian pushed me to use a class with dynamically defined methods. Will post the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Vaughn Cato points out that one could just assign into `locals()[object_type] = factory(object_type)`. However [the Python docs prohibit this](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals): "Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter"

D. Shawley points out that it would be wiser to use a `dict()` object which entries would hold the functions. Access would be simple by using `create['cat']()` in the parser. While this is compelling I do not like the syntax overhead of the brackets and ticks required.

J.F. Sebastian points to classes. And this is what I ended up with:

```
# Omitting code of these classes for clarity
class Entity:
    def __init__(file_name, line_number):
        # Store location, good for debug, messages, and general indexing

# The following classes are the real objects to be generated by a parser
# Their constructors must consume whatever data is provided by the tokens
# as well as calling super() to forward the file_name,line_number info.
class Cat(Entity): pass
class Camel(Entity): pass

class Parser:
    def parse_file(self, fn):
        # ...

        # Function factory to wrap object constructor calls
        def create_factory(obj_type):
            def creator(text, line_number, token):
                try:
                    return obj_type(*token,
                                    file_name=fn, line_number=line_number)
                except Exception as e:
                    # For debug of constructor during development
                    print(e)
            return creator

        # Helper class, serving as a 'dictionary' of obj construction functions
        class create: pass
            for obj_type in (Cat, Camel):
                setattr(create,
                        obj_type.__name__.lower(),
                        create_factory(obj_type))

        # Parsing code now can use (again simplified for clarity):
        expression = Keyword('cat').setParseAction(create.cat)
```

This is helper code for deploying a [pyparsing parser](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). D. Shawley is correct in that the dict would actually more easily allow to dynamically generate the parser grammar.